# Create a temporary file and open it

Tags: android, file

I know how to create a temporary file (code below) but in my case I want to create an exact copy of my SQLite internal database and open it as temporary, is it possible? I did not find anything in the documentation.

```
File file; 
file = File.createTempFile(filename, null, this.getCacheDir());
```

Comment: Of course. One can copy any file. So also that database file.

Comment: Just copy your DB file, open it as regular file access, delete it manually. DB file should in "/data/data/your.app.package/databases/your_db.sqlite"

Comment: `know how to create a temporary file (code below)`. Well that is not much of a file. An empty file only. To put some content in it you need much more code.

Comment: I can easily open the internal database, does anyone have an example of opening a temporary SQLite database?